# how to remove php sessid on user leave from web site

Tags: php

I'm using secure money transfer web site.So i need to set new session every time same user comes to my web site from same machine .

when user leave from my web site want to remove php sessid .If user again come to the web site have to set new session

Comment: `Destroy` the session with `session_destroy()`

Comment: [`session_destroy();`](http://www.php.net/session_destroy) will destroy all of it. You can [unset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) individual session names also.

Comment: Commenters... how exactly do you plan on calling `session_destroy()` when the *user leaves the site*?

Comment: With a logout button perhaps? Most or all financial institutions have them, right? @NiettheDarkAbsol Least, I hope so. And sessions don't last forever. Servers have a default session timeout that usually only lasts approx. 30 mins. or depending on how the server's configuration is set up.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The problem with logout buttons is that people don't always click them - I have the bad habit of just closing my PayPal tab when done with it, although I'm on a computer that nobody else has physical access to when I do, so that's okay... right? XD

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on that. I was just adding about how session life doesn't last forever and are automatically deleted after a short period of time. My server's session life only last 30 minutes, and I'm not a "banker" ;-) so, one would assume that they (the big bankers) have some smart webmasters that will basically do the same, right? @NiettheDarkAbsol

Answer (score 2):

Set the session to have a short expiry, such as 5 minutes.

Then use AJAX to ping the server every minute or so to keep the session alive.

When the user leaves your site, they will be kept logged in for 5 minutes — ample time to go "oops I didn't mean to close that, re-open closed tab!" but short enough for it to count as them logging out when they leave.

Comment: Hoping that JS is enabled of course. For Ajax anyway. Otherwise, it's `Plan B`

Comment: my requirement is when client closing the browser tab without clicking log out button, on that time have to remove session as well as sessid(session kookie in user machine).

Comment: That is not possible. This is the closest you can get.